# How to use Heya email campaigns with GoodJob instead of Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, rails-activejob

I'm trying to send email campaigns in a rails app with the [Heya](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/heya) gem and [GoodJob](https://github.com/bensheldon/good_job). The example in the Heya readme as well as the [Heya example app](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/heya-app) uses Sidekiq as the Active Job backend.

I'm confused about how to actually send the Heya campaigns with [GoodJob](https://github.com/bensheldon/good_job).

The docs for Heya show this example of starting Sidekick: `bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q heya`

I assume that there is a Job queue somewhere in the gem called "Heya", but I can't find this in the source code. Do I need to create one?

Do I need to create a job that runs the Heya scheduler? While the example app uses Sidekiq, I also don't see any [custom jobs in that app](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/heya-app/tree/master/app/jobs).

I have the following setup for GoodJob and it appears to be running fine with `good_job start` which should run all of the jobs and queues, but I've also tried `good_job start --queues=heya,default`.

Here is the relevant code:

Profile.dev

```
web: bin/rails server -p 3000
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch
worker: bundle exec good_job start
```

config/initializers/heya.rb

```
Heya.configure do |config|
  config.user_type = "User"

  config.campaigns.priority = [
    "WelcomeCampaign",
  ]
end
```

app/jobs/application_job.rb

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  # Automatically retry jobs that encountered a deadlock
  # retry_on ActiveRecord::Deadlocked

  # Most jobs are safe to ignore if the underlying records are no longer available
  # discard_on ActiveJob::DeserializationError
end
```

app/campaigns/application_campaign.rb

```
class ApplicationCampaign < Heya::Campaigns::Base
  segment :email_subscriber?

  default from: "#{I18n.t('settings.site_name')} <#{I18n.t('settings.newsletter_email')}>"
end
```

app/campaigns/welcome_campaign.rb

```
class WelcomeCampaign < ApplicationCampaign
  default wait: 5.minutes,
    layout: "newsletter"

  step :intro, wait: 0.minutes,
               subject: "Welcome to #{I18n.t('settings.site_name')}"
end
```

I also have a layout and views for the campaign similar to [the Heya example app](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/heya-app/tree/master/app/views/heya/campaign_mailer/demo_campaign), and I'm using [Mailcatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher) to see if any email is being sent.

What am I missing to send these emails with Heya and GoodJob?

Note that I'm subscribing the users on signups like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  after_create_commit :add_user_to_newsletters

  private
    def add_user_to_newsletters
      WelcomeCampaign.add(self)
      EvergreenCampaign.add(self)
      self.update(email_subscriber: true)
    end
end
```

And the default segment in campaigns/application_campaign.rb is `segment :email_subscriber?`

If I run `User.last.email_subscriber?` in the console to check this it returns `true`.

I feel like I'm missing something about how Heya connects to Active Job that is not obvious in the Heya docs.

Also, not sure if this is related, but I added this to config/puma.rb

```
# https://github.com/bensheldon/good_job#execute-jobs-async--in-process
before_fork do
  GoodJob.shutdown
end

on_worker_boot do
  GoodJob.restart
end

on_worker_shutdown do
  GoodJob.shutdown
end

MAIN_PID = Process.pid
at_exit do
  GoodJob.shutdown if Process.pid == MAIN_PID
end

preload_app!
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the heya scheduler periodically? `$ rails heya:scheduler`

It looks like [you could create your own background job](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/heya/blob/042917500d91ded0e638124fffd4a595d88147e8/lib/tasks/heya_tasks.rake#L6) to be run using GoodJob Cron, by executing `Heya::Campaigns::Scheduler.new.run` to run the scheduler and enqueue the emails.

Reading the ["Running the Scheduler"](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/heya#running-the-scheduler) part of the README explains what's happening:

To start queuing emails, run the scheduler task periodically:

```bash
rails heya:scheduler
```

Heya uses ActiveJob to send emails in the background. Make sure your
ActiveJob backend is configured to process the `heya` queue. By default, GoodJob runs from all queues `"*"`.

You can change Heya's default queue using the `queue` option:

```rb
# app/campaigns/application_campaign.rb
class ApplicationCampaign < Heya::Campaigns::Base
  default queue: "custom"
end
```